# Excluding folders from a roaming profile, client-side

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, user-accounts, roaming-profile

I am using a laptop connected to our company's domain network, and after logging in this morning it told me that I have exceeded my roaming profile space. After looking into the issue I realized that most of this space was taken up by the `.android` and `.eclipse` folders (I am developing Android apps) in my user folder. I was hence wondering whether there was any way to exclude these from being synced with the roaming profile, as there is no reason for them to be synced in the first place. I have googled the issue, but most guides (e.g. [this one](http://www.online-it-support.co.uk/?p=310)) focus on how to do this on the server side, and I was wondering if it was possible to do this on the laptop itself, without having to contact our network administrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a description of where the roaming profile exclusion list is stored:

http://helgeklein.com/blog/2008/11/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-roaming-profiles/

Hint: look for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\ExcludeProfileDirs`

Comment: It worked, after I made the change and restarted! I don't know how I missed this setting. Thank you so much!